# "$" Undefined when using jQuery in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, visual-studio

I am trying to learn how to get JSON data using jQuery (using Visual Studio) but am hitting a runtime error in VS.

Error message: **JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined**

It seems that VS is just not recognizing jQuery. Alternatively, I have tried referencing the external jQuery library via their CDN but it did not resolve it.

Anyone have an idea why I am running into the error?

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>JSON Test</title>

    <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/js/jquery-1.10.2.min"></script>
    <script src="/js/default.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="canWeGetData()">Get Data!</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Default.JS:

```
function canWeGetData() {

var error = "Null data!";
var success = "Good data!";

$.getJSON("http://ip.jsontest.com/?callback=showMyIP", function (data) {

    if (data == null) {
        document.writeln(error);
    }
    else {
        document.writeln(success);
    }

});
```

};

Comment: your jquery file are not getting loaded properly try like this <script src="~/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

Comment: whether the path to the jquery library is correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jquery isn't present.

Look at this line:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> <!-- you missed the .js -->
```

Also, Check whether the path is correct. Or simply use

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
```

Comment: *Facepalm* Thanks :) I was using the URL for jQuery via _<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>_ earlier and was getting the same error, but I might have been calling it after my default.js

Answer (score 2):

doubt jquery is not present

try

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! You're right. jQuery wasn't being called correctly :|